# Resigning while on Sick Leave

Tags: resignation, notice-period, canada, leave

I live in Canada and have been on sick leave for 4 months. My leave will come to an end in one month. I understand that a member of my team has been filling in as an interim director in my absence.

I went on leave due to stress causing debilitating anxiety and depression, but my employers do not know the reason for the leave and expect me to come back with accommodations at the end of the month.

I am now clear that I will not return to the role and am about to tender my resignation. I am required, as a director, to give 4 weeks notice. Should the resignation letter acknowledge the 4 weeks, or can my resignation be "effective immediately". I understand that I have a legal obligation to my contract, but given my sick leave, am I required to work them? Should I offer something like "if further action is required by me, I am happy to explore ways to support the transition, as my capacity allows" or is it fair to assume my sick leave will cancel out the 4 weeks notice required by my contract? I've also considered checking in with my supervisor, letting her know I plan to resign and asking if I am going to be held to this part of the contract given my leave. However, I really hope that I have no further obligations to the employer and do not need to be present at the workplace again.

Comment: What country do you live in?

Comment: I live in Canada?

Answer (score 2):

[united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom)

Depending on the stakes, you might want to consult an employment lawyer before doing anything.

But in general, if you are sick then you do not need to attend under your employment contract, and you also do not need to attend and resume your duties under the contract if doing so is liable to make you sick again (if a period of absence has already allowed a degree of recovery).

Your employer is likely to welcome your resignation if the circumstances are that you are unlikely ever to return.

There is a possibility you might, however, have to disclose that the role has made you sick and to what extent, as part of explaining the situation to your employer - especially if you cannot cope with even limited duties or provide any cooperation in a handover.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in discussing these things face to face, especially if you want to leave at good terms.

Talk to your supervisor first.  They may have some suggestions.  Then talk to HR if they have such a department/person.

If you meet with a difficult response then consult with an employment lawyer.